# Can apple mail on iOS be used to configure server-side rules on exchange server

Tags: email, exchange

When using an Exchange mailbox, Exchange supports server-side rules to filter and sort mails automatically. This works on the server, so the client does not have to be online.

Those rules can be configured with Outlook and with Outlook Web Access, but can they also be managed used Apple Mail for Exchange mailboxes?

Comment: How are you getting rules created in Outlook to apply server side? Exchange rules that are applied even if Outlook is offline can only be created in OWA or ECP as far as I have been ever able to find. Which would make any rules created in mail.app on macOS apply only while mail.app is running, just like with Outlook on Macs or Windows. Do you have a procedure that adds a server side rule from the Outlook application? If so I would love to know what *that* is.

Comment: Apple Mail does not do server-side rules for any mail server.

Comment: @SteveChambers The rules dialog in Outlook (at least on Windows) automatically creates server based rules when configured within a Exchange mailbox. This is about mail filter rules inside a mailbox (same as OWA), not about transport rules (as in ECP).

Comment: Actually the only way to create server-side rules is in the Automatic replies dialog and it is a much simpler interface. Rules created in `Outlook > Home > Move > Rules` are strictly client side rules and only work when Outlook is open, running and checking for mail

Comment: @SteveChambers That is simply not true. I have several rules and my Outlook is not running and still those rules are applied, as I can check through my Android device for example.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot.

But if you have access to an Exchange mailbox from Apple Mail, these days the chances are close to certainty that you'd have Outlook Web Access in some form, and from there, you can set server-side rules.